# WinApi: CreateFile() hangs for long time attempting to open PIPE on Linux network client

Tags: winapi, pipe

I have an issue with `CreateFile()` hanging for several minutes when attempting to open a named pipe on a Linux network client/server.   I'm able to scan the subnet for IP's, then probe it to see if it has a port 445 or 139 open.   But then it attempts to connect to a named pipe via `CreateFile()` and that hangs for several minutes (it doesn't have the named pipe, only windows clients have it).   I tried `CreateFile()` in a thread and timing out waiting for the thread to end then calling `CancelSynchronousIo()` but that doesn't help, it still won't complete until the several minutes are over.

Is there anyway to prevent that?

Comment: So, you have a Windows pipe client trying to connect to a Linux pipe server? Is that even supported?

Comment: *`CancelSynchronousIo` that doesn't help* - are you sure ? in my fast test this is help (and `CreateFile` return `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED`). this of course depend from driver implementation, but think must work in concrete case

Comment: it doesn't know what os the client uses, it just knows it's there and supports SMB, yes, that `CancelSynchronousIo` didn't report any problems but it didn't stop the `CreateFile` from hanging.   It's an old linux debian version, real old probably squeeze or older.